# argument type 'List<dynamic> Function()' can't be assigned - or deserializing Map<int, List<dynamic>>

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, dart, serialization

I receive the error `The argument type 'List<dynamic> Function({bool growable})' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.` with my best attempt to transform  json into a `Map<int, List<dynamic>>` object.

```dart
class MyDataClass {
  int id;
  Map<int, List<dynamic>> data;
  MyDataClass({required this.id, required this.data});

  factory MyDataClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MyDataClass(
    id: json["id"],
    data: Map<int, List<dynamic>>.from(json["data"])
      .map((key, problemList) =>
        MapEntry(key, (problemList.map((dSet) => dSet.fromJson())).toList)
      )
  ),
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `.toList()` instead of `.toList` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @esentis commented, you aren't calling the `toList()` function (since you are missing the `()`), but just accessing the field's getter, thus returning an instance of a `Function`.

Changing your code to `.toList()` should do the trick.

Comment: now I get an idea of the error message's meaning... Cheers! After all the time to reach this code my eyes turned tired, I guess